# vertex that can reach every other vertex in the graph, imply every vertex can reach each other?

Tags: graph-theory

Given an undirected graph G.

If there is a vertex that can reach every other vertex in the graph, does that imply, every other vertex can reach each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If we are trying to find a walk between vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$ in this graph, we can use the fact that there exists a walk from $v_1$ to $V$ and a walk from $v_2$ to $V$ to create a walk from $v_1$ to $v_2$ through the vertex $V$, where $V$ is the vertex that connects to all other vertices.

Comment: To be more precise, it implies that there is a *walk* from $v_1$ to $V$ to $v_2$, however there need not necessarily be a **path** from $v_1$ to $v_2$ which passes through $V$.  The existence of a walk from $v_1$ to $v_2$ will necessarily guarantee the existence of a path from $v_1$ to $v_2$ however $V$'s involvement in the path is unknown.  The difference between walks and paths is that walks are allowed to reuse vertices and edges whereas paths are not allowed that luxury.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes thank you very much, I edited the answer. Its been a little while since my graph theory course.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to see this calculate the square of the adjacency matrix of the graph, $A^2$. You'll recognize that every matrix element is $>0$, indicating that there is at least one 2-step-path from every vertex to any other...

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question.  You seem to be working under the assumption that there is a vertex that is **adjacent to** every other vertex of the graph.  That is not how I interpret the problem, which is that there is a vertex **which has the property that there exists a path from it to any other** (which is not necessarily of length one).  Are you suggesting that the adjacency matrix for a connected graph of large girth has all positive entries?

Comment: @JMoravitz I interpreted "reach" as "reach in one step" right. It seems to answer OP's question, but you're right: It's not perfectly clear. What would your suggestion "adjacency matrix for a connected graph of large girth wth  all positive entries" imply?

Comment: That every entry has some power for which it is positive, but there is not necessarily a power for which every entry is positive.  Consider the graph C_4 for counter example.